# i need a query which returns 1 column 5 rows and 2nd column 10 rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

here is my query

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(
     (
     select subjectshrt from subject_definition sd  join student_subject ss
     on(sd.sdsrno =ss.sdsrno1) where sd.tpbp LIKE ('p%')
      )
,0)A,
ISNULL(
     (
     select subjectshrt from subject_definition sd  join student_subject ss
     on(sd.sdsrno =ss.sdsrno2) where sd.tpbp LIKE ('p%')
      )
,0)b
```

here first select query return 1 row and 2nd returns multiple rows
and am getting a error like

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

so what should i do to make this query work

Comment: When posting code, please format it (use the {} button above the question editing box)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well that error is because isNULL needs a scalar value for all of it's arguments. When multiple records are returned within the isNULL function, the IsNull gives you this error.

Comment: Also, you can't have a query where you have different columns returning different numbers of records. The best you can do is have the columns with fewer records returned give a null value where the other columns have values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this instead

```
select
    case when exists(
        select subjectshrt from subject_definition sd  join student_subject ss
        on (sd.sdsrno = ss.sdsrno1) where sd.tpbp LIKE ('p%')
    ) then 1 else 0 end as A,
    case when exists(
        select subjectshrt from subject_definition sd  join student_subject ss
        on (sd.sdsrno = ss.sdsrno2) where sd.tpbp LIKE ('p%')
    ) then 1 else 0 end as B
```

but it would probably be much better to write a select statement with joins and get results as appropriate.

```
select case when sh.sdrno = ss.sdrno1 then sd.subjectshrt else 0 end as A, ... -- similar for B
from subject_definition sd
    left join student_subject ss
    on ((sh.sdsrno = ss.sdrno1) or (sh.sdsrno = ss.sdrno2))
where sd.tpbp like 'p%'
```

Checking execution plans for comparison reasons strongly advised.

Comment: +1, you seem to be more on the mark. I guess it's just an integrity/match check.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you modify the code to use one query and check `ON (sd.sdsrno IN (ss.sdsrno1,ss.sdsrno2))`? it seems like that is the only change here.

*(Or maybe I'm missing the end result here. if so, please feel free to post a couple of example outputs you'd like to see)*

```
SELECT  COALESCE(subjectshirt,0) AS subjectshirt
FROM    subject_definition
  JOIN  student_subject
  ON    (sd.sdsrno IN (ss.sdsrno1,ss.sdsrno2))
WHERE sd.tpbp LIKE 'p%'
```

Or "SELECT TOP 2" is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

try using something like

```
SELECT isnull(sd1.subjectshrt,0) as A , isnull(sd2.subjectshrt,0) as B
from student_subject ss left join subject_definition sd1 on sd1.sdsrno =ss.sdsrno1,
left join subject_definition sd2 on sd2.sdsrno =ss.sdsrno2
```